# Samsung Gas dryer power issues

Tags: dryer

I have a Samsung DV410 Gas Dryer.  Towards the end of last year it started powering off mid cycle.  It then worked fine until a few days ago, when summer finally hit and it was really hot and humid in the house ~80F.  When I use the dryer, sometimes the control panel will start to dim, sometimes is shuts off completely.  The dryer does not have to be running for this to happen, just the control panel.  Sometimes it works perfectly fine.  I've contemplated exploratory surgery checking all the connections but I thought I would ask around before I attempt it.

Here is a video of the behavior when it happens right away.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_mNOq8zez4

Comment: start troubleshooting on the outside of the dryer ....  monitor the voltage at the power outlet as the dryer is started ....  or plug the dryer into an outlet that is on a different breaker

Comment: Thanks, it's not the breaker as the washer works fine.  They are on different outlets though.  I've done 2 loads without issue on the other outlet, and I had a 100W bulb on the old one as a test, but I did not notice any issues.  I'll have to wait until the heat and humidity returns before I try again.

Comment: ok, it has nothing to do with the outlet, breaker, heat, or humidity.  After 2 weeks of working fine it's acting up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to replace the control board on the dryer.